# Ordenar resultados MySQL por preferência

Tags: mysql

Eu possuo uma tabela de `produtos` onde se há a coluna primária `id`, desejo selecionar produtos com o nome provável de "%TV%" entretanto eu quero que seja ordenado de forma `DESC` normalmente, contudo quero que alguns `IDS` venham primeiro que outros, os `IDS` que estão na promoção, por exemplo `5, 4` respectivamente.

Nesse exemplo a ordem de resultado (pelo ID) deveria ser: `5, 4, e depois os outros, como 1, 2, 3, 6`...

```
id | name     |
---------------
 1 | tv       |   
 2 | core     |   
 3 | tv other |   
 4 | tv board |   
 5 | apple TV |   
 6 | core     |
```

Comment: E como você sabe quais são `IDS` dos produtos em promoção? Há outra tabela relacionada?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade não, esses `IDS` seriam inseridos direto na query mesmo..

Comment: Não não, mas só por essa tabela com apenas esses dois campos não tem como saber quais `IDS` estão em promoção. Como você define isso?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade eles são definidos manualmente, por que são fixos, é como se eu reservasse 5 promoções, no caso 5 IDS (1-5) e eu colocasse aquele produto com uma dessas IDS.

Comment: Mas tem alguma coluna tipo uma `flag` verdadeiro/falso que indique que aquele produto está em promoção? Se não, você precisar rever como está a estrutura relacional disso.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade estava pensando em fazer duas `ORDER`? Pensei em algo relacionado mas infelizmente a estrutura não permite. Não há nenhum indicador além dos `IDS` especiais.

Comment: Há como adicionar pelo menos uma coluna para indicar que o produto está em promoção? Os IDS especiais são fixos?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade sim, eles são fixos (digo fixos mas são alterados em um longo prazo de tempo). Infelizmente não, esse indicador que está em promoção ou não é apenas os IDS que recebo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que isso resolve o seu problema:

```
SELECT *
FROM produtos
ORDER BY (id IN (5,4)) DESC, id
```